# config.kit.adapter should be an object with an "adapt" method

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to use the @sveltejs/adapter-static in my Svelte Kit app (want to turn it into an SPA).
I installed the adapter static with npm i @sveltejs/adapter-static.

The code in the svelte.config.cjs looks like this

```
kit: {
    // By default, `npm run build` will create a standard Node app.
    // You can create optimized builds for different platforms by
    // specifying a different adapter
    adapter: adapter({
        fallback: 'app.html'
    }),
```

When I start my app with `npm run dev` I get the following error:
`config.kit.adapter should be an object with an "adapt" method`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

just install it with the following command:

```
npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static@next
```

credits goes to: https://github.com/GrygrFlzr

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I feel kinda dumb now haha :)

Comment: hehe no problem ^^ @Fugi

Comment: Did not work for me!! Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @MBParvezRony not that I am aware of. You should ask on the Svelte Discord server. They have a pretty good response time and quality answers most of the time.

Comment: how do i specify an output directory?

Comment: using @next just introduces whatever other bugs the next version brings! Technically it solves this issue, but it also brings a firehose of problems

Comment: @Jan this should be known since SvelteKit is still in development. You can see https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/milestones for further information on the progress of SvelteKit towards version 1.0.